# How to change the order of HTML element (images) onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beginner in HTML/SCC/JC and I try to solve by myself. But this one have too much of my time and I decided to ask for help. To tell the truth I chaked for answerd in the internet)

I need to change the order of images by click on the buttom, how to do this?

```js
JS: function change_order() { } ???
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"> 
              
        <input id="b1" value="Change the image order" onclick="change_order()" type="button"/>
       
        <h1 style="font-size: 12"> Header HeaderHeaderHeader</h1> 
        <p style="font-size:8"> text text text </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="two">
       
        <img id="pict_01" src="https://www.khanacademy.org/images/topic-icons/math/doodling-in-math.png?v2" />
        <img id="pict_02" src="http://www.milldamschool.ik.org/img/d666f5fc-db14-11de-a689-0014220c8f46-5812526.jpg" />
        <img id="pict_03" src="http://www.birdsontheblog.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/maths.jpg" />
        
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS I placed the columns and images (static position).
Actually I'm not sure about onclick buttum if it's conneted to JS.
Full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SantaUA/ovcheyfa/) http://jsfiddle.net/SantaUA/ovcheyfa/

Comment: You have to learn javascript my friend. Check out eloquentjavascript.net.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you on the right lines

```
$('img').on("click", function() {
  $(this).insertBefore( $(this).prev('img') );
});
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/ndhjgu44/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. You will need to get the id of the element in javascript, the picture in this case and change its source or src. 
So create something like **this**

```
var firstpic = document.getElementById("pict_01");
firstpic.src = "secondpicture.jpg";
```

The previous code will put the second image in your first image. Just repeat the following code for all pictures and you will achieve what u asked for.
Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is put all the images into an array and then shuffle the order of the array.  After you change the order of the array, you can output the new array back out to the screen.

I've put together an example to show you how to do this correctly using jQuery.  The following sample will shuffle your images randomly every time you push the Shuffle Me button.

Note that I changed the name of your div from id="two" to id="picContainer".

**HTML:**

```
<div id="picContainer">

    <img id="pict_01" src="https://www.khanacademy.org/images/topic-icons/math/doodling-in-math.png?v2" />
    <img id="pict_02" src="http://www.milldamschool.ik.org/img/d666f5fc-db14-11de-a689-0014220c8f46-5812526.jpg" />
    <img id="pict_03" src="http://www.birdsontheblog.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/maths.jpg" />

</div>
```

**JS (jQuery):**

```
//grab the div that contains our images
var container = $('#picContainer');

//grab our button
var button = $('.shuffleMe');

//search through div and add all images to an array
var images = $(container).find('img');

//console out the images array
console.log('images: ', images);

//function to shuffle our array
//using the Fisher-Yates Shuffle.
//See https://github.com/coolaj86/knuth-shuffle
function shuffleArray(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

//shuffle our image arrray and create a new array with random ordered images
var randomImages = shuffleArray(images);

//console out the images to we can see they changed order
console.log("random image: ", randomImages);

//empty our image container and
//append our images in a new random order 
//to the same container
function renderImages(array){
   $(container).empty();

   $.each(array, function( index, value ) {
      $(container).append(value);
   });
}


//call the renderImages function when our button is pressed
$(button).on("click", function(){
    //render the random images to the screen
    randomImages = shuffleArray(images);
    renderImages(randomImages);
});
```

I hope this helps.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zkoCl